# parse first column of command output, get corresponding second column value

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am executing a command that outputs a table, as such:

```
firstValue:   a
secondValue:  b.y7
thirdValue:   c-x-g 10:42 GMT
```

Say I need the `secondValue`. I can't do this by row number, because sometimes the output could look like this:

```
firstValue:    a
surprisevalue: d
secondValue:   b.y7
thirdValue:    c-x-g 10:42 GMT
```

How can I do this by finding a certain string ("secondValue") in the first column, and returning the corresponding string in the second column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe the command through `awk`; tell it to search for a line that starts with `secondValue` and output the second field in that line:

```
$ command-that-outputs-the-table | awk '/^secondValue:/ {print $2}'
```